# Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, flash-cs5

So i am playing around with some exmaples that come with the tuio as3 library and i am getting an error on launch that i have never encountered before and don't know how to fix.

it compiles with no errors however on launch i get this output:

`ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1"]`

does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An IOErrorEvent object is dispatched when an error causes input or output operations to fail.

So I'm guessing either you have no localhost configured or your SWF was compiled with the "Local Playback Security" set to "Access Local Files Only".

Most likely the compile setting.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I tried to connect to a port where no server was set up.

Resolved by connecting to correct port in socket.connect.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly related to this question (because I don't get it on 127.0.0.1), but since this question came up very high on my Google searches, I'll mention that I'm getting it on AIR 3.2 while connecting to another machine which went to sleep (network activity doesn't wake it up).

Waking it up solves the issue.