# AIR Local Socket Connection - Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: localhost

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412788/error-2031-socket-error-url-127-0-0-1)

I am trying to create a local socket connection to serproxy, I am using FlashDevelop and keep getting the error:

Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: localhost

I can successfully create the same connection with telnet/putty etc, and really don't know what to try now. In flash develop compiler options I have set Use Network Services to true.

What else can I try?

Comment: If this question isn't a duplicate, please edit it a bit to reflect why and flag it for moderator attention to be re-opened. Even though it is closed, you can still make edits.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was marked as an exact duplicate (assuming the "duplicate" question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412788/error-2031-socket-error-url-127-0-0-1). The socket policy for AIR apps is very different than for web-based flex/flash apps. I came here hoping to find an answer as why I would ever get error #2031 when connecting to a local network port in an AIR app. Alas... :(

Answer (score 0):

looks like server is not configured/launched or SWF was compiled with `Local Playback Security`=`Access Local Files Only`.

Comment: **Moderator Note** _Comments under this answer degraded into noise and were subsequently removed. Please keep comments constructive and relevant to the parent question or answer._